# Facebook ads, add customer page to business manager

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

What I want to do is to be able to create and publish FB ads from my fb account and publish it on other users fb pages using fb api.

User can install my app which will ask for manage_pages+business_management permission along with some other needed permissions.(this part is done for test app and it's working) and then users can create fb ads on my platform and connect there pages to the ad they have created.
I am able to create fb ads also from my platform but not able to connect users pages to my fb ads.

1. I have one main account with business manager + app(dev mode) connected to it + system users, test account etc..

so far I have figured out that I have to add the other fb user pages to my business pages and to do that according to the doc, first I have to install the app for system users by using below curl request.

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/businessmanager/systemuser/v2.10
>   Installing Apps
>   A system user or an admin system user must install the app that will be used for generating the token. That means to allow the app to call APIs on behalf of this system user or admind system user. Both system user and app should belong to a same business manager
>   To install an app for a system user you need following things:
>   *       access_token: of an admin user, admin system user, or another system user if generated
>   *       business_app: the app ID being installed
>   To install an application for system user, make a POST request as shown in the example below:

curl \

-F "business_app=APP_ID" \

-F "access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN" \

"https://graph.facebook.com/API_VERSION/APP_SCOPED_SYSTEM_USER_ID/applications"

> This call will return a boolean result indicating installation was successful. If any of the restrictions are not met, you will see appropriate error message.

but it never works...

my first question is before going any further

1. Is it even possible to install the test app which is always in development mode for system users?

if the answer is "No" then i'll have make my main app live and submit it for review so I can needed permissions which are not there in main app which doesn't sound reasonable to me, I should be able to do this with test app in dev mode.

but if the answer is yes then please let me know how.
When I try I always get this error

> Error: Requires business_management permission to manage the object

I have added system user to Advert account as an admin
I have added system user to test app as an admin
I checked business_management checkbox when I created the system user token

any help is highly appreciated!

ps: pls correct me if you think this is not the right way to achieve my goal

Comment: Or in short what is the best way to add customer fb page to ads created in my fb account

Answer (score 3):

Well if someone comes around to this page for looking for an answer then it's damn simple, special privilege is required to do this and you'll have to contact facebook. it's that easy -_-, still haven't got the privilege yet so can't add anything else...