# Q: Facebook Business Manager - manage Pages (ads)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm having trouble finding solution for my client's new **web app** - within this app, customers will be able to create ads for facebook, instagram and google (and others in future), all from 1 place. So, somehow I need to be able to manage ads for customers' Pages. For personal accounts it's "quite simple", through ads manager, big green button 'Add people', but I need this permission for Pages, not for personal accounts. 
We already have approved "*ads_management*", "*ads_read*" and "*manage_pages*" (I'm not 100% sure if we'll need manage_pages permission) - we'll probably ask for "*Ads Management Standard Access*" too.

After some research, I think this whole thing might be possible through **Business Manager** (so we'll need "*business_management*" permission too, right?), then in app settings, there's business manager ID input (for linking business account with app). 
Here's my proposed solution (simplified):

1. in our web app, customers will provide us with url/ID of their Page
2. api call to check whether logged-in user is administrator of provided Page
3. api call to add this Page to Business manager (send invitation)
4. api call to check if user/Page has accepted invitation - if so, we'll be able to manage their ads

Question is, is this (**very simplified**) solution possible? Will it work? There are dozens of APIs and I'm not sure I picked the right one.
Development is at early stage, so we don't have any in-depth research yet.

Something very similar might be here - [Facebook ads, add customer page to business manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45575047/facebook-ads-add-customer-page-to-business-manager) but it's 2 years old and after all scandals, there were a lot of changes in APIs, so I'm not sure whether it's still actual.

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. & 2. should be replaced by asking the customer for `manage_pages` permission (or at least `pages_show_list`, but you’re probably going to need `manage_pages` anyway later on), and then requesting the list of pages they have admin access to via API (`/me/accounts`, using their user access token.)

Comment: @misorude you're right, many thanks!